# no full control for datepicker validation using input matDatepickerFilter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to call a method within the method that filters the dates for my Datepicker Angular Material component.

But I came across a problem where within that method as programmed, I can't get access to this.

**How can I execute this method by accessing this and filtering the dates?**

My code

```html
<mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
   <input matInput formControlName="inicioAtendimento (dateChange)="updateMinMaxDate()"
          [min]="minDateAtendimento" [max]="maxDateAtendimento [matDatepicker]="picker"
          [matDatepickerFilter]="filterDatePicker()" placeholder="Início do atendimento">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
   <mat-hint>Dia em que você inicia o atendimento.</mat-hint>
   <mat-error>Data informada inválida.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
public filterDatePicker(date): boolean {
   let dataBlocked: boolean;

   // I can't access this one here
   if (this.bloqueioData && this.produtoControl) {
      const produto = this.produtoControl.value;
      const datasBloqueadas = this.bloqueioData.produtos[produto.id] as string[];

      if (datasBloqueadas) {
         dataBlocked = 
            datasBloqueadas.find((v: string) => v === date.toISOString().split('T')[0]) 
            ? true : false;
      }
   }

   const day = date.toDate().getDay();
   return (day !== 0 && day !== 6) || dataBlocked;
}
```

Comment: did you try with the arrow function like `filterDatePicker = (date) => {}`. In your datePicker, don't invoke the function,  [matDatepickerFilter]="filterDatePicker"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
updateMinMaxDate(){
this.filterDatePicker;
}


  filterDatePicker = (d: Date): boolean  => {

        let dataBlocked: boolean;

        // I can't access this one here
        if (this.bloqueioData && this.produtoControl) {
          const produto = this.produtoControl.value;
          const datasBloqueadas = this.bloqueioData.produtos[produto.id] as string[];
          if (datasBloqueadas) {
            dataBlocked = datasBloqueadas.find((v: string) => v ===
              date.toISOString().split('T')[0]) ? true : false;
          }
        }

        const day = date.toDate().getDay();
        return (day !== 0 && day !== 6) || dataBlocked;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation matDatepickerFilter is an input property that expects a function:

```html
@Input()
matDatepickerFilter: (date: D) => boolean
```

that for a given argument date will return true or false depending whether date is valid or not.

In your code there are at least 2 mistakes:

- there is a method call instead of passing a reference to a function,
- you are using method and not binding this.

It should be rewritten as below(I did not tested it):

```html
[matDatepickerFilter]="filterDatePicker.bind(this)"
```

or use arrow function which automatically correctly binds this:

```html
filterDatePicker = (d: Date): boolean => {

    let dataBlocked: boolean;

    // I can't access this one here
    if (this.bloqueioData && this.produtoControl) {
      const produto = this.produtoControl.value;
      const datasBloqueadas = this.bloqueioData.produtos[produto.id] as string[];
      if (datasBloqueadas) {
        dataBlocked = datasBloqueadas.find((v: string) => v ===
          date.toISOString().split('T')[0]) ? true : false;
      }
    }

    const day = date.toDate().getDay();
    return (day !== 0 && day !== 6) || dataBlocked;
 }
```

And in html template bind to it:

```html
 [matDatepickerFilter]="filterDatePicker"
```